# username & password with presto-python-client

Tags: python-2.7, presto

I am trying to replace 
jaydebeapi with the presto-python-client by facebook
the question is how to replace the authentication bit

```
db = jaydebeapi.connect(connection['jclass'], connection['host'],[ connection['user'], connection['pass']], connection['jar'])
```

while with presto-python-client

```
import prestodb
conn= prestodb.dbapi.connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=8080,
    user='the-user',
    catalog='the-catalog',
    schema='the-schema',
    isolation_level=transaction.IsolationLevel.REPEATABLE_READ,
)
```

and I couldn't find anywhere to specify how to pass a password.
The reason for this change is that I am getting ambigous errors when trying to pass long queries (18k characters) with jaydebeapi

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @CristhianBoujon sorry man just saw your comment now :)
we ended up using SQLAlchemy so the solution is 




   from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
   engine = create_engine('presto://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/hive'.format(connection['user'],connection['pass'],connection['host'],int(connection['port'])), connect_args={'protocol': 'https',  'requests_kwargs': {'verify': False}})
        db = engine.raw_connection()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we ended up using SQLAlchemy so the solution is

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine 
engine = create_engine('presto://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/hive'.format(connection['user'],connection['pass'],connection['host'],int(connection['port'])), connect_args={'protocol': 'https', 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': False}}) 
db = engine.raw_connection()
```

Comment: I'm getting `NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:presto`. What installation of sqlalchemy are you using?

Comment: @DimaLituiev according to the documentation https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/   you should also install PyHive

Answer (score 2):

Now the old method are deprecated, so here is the new one to connect to presto

```
cursor = presto.connect(presto_host,
                                presto_port,
                                requests_kwargs={'auth': HTTPBasicAuth(presto_username, presto_password)},
                                poll_interval=1,
                                protocol='https',
                                source='pyhive').cursor()
```