# Push Dataframe into Presto

Tags: pandas, dataframe, load, presto

I have a dataframe with about 10 columns.
There is a presto database where i want to load the dataframe into.

Normally this type of load is straight forward with something like:

```
df.to_sql('tablename', con=conn, index=False)
```

There is no issue with the connection.
The error I receive looks like:

> PrestoUserError: PrestoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=SYNTAX_ERROR,
> message="line 1:61: mismatched input ';'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+',
> '-', '.', '/', 'AND', 'AT', 'EXCEPT', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT',
> 'LIMIT', 'OR', 'ORDER', 'UNION', '[', '||', ",
> query_id=20210809_14id)

Surely there is a simple way to load data from python pandas df to presto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to do this with **sqlalchemy**:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

connection_string = 'presto://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/hive'.format(user, password, host, int(port))
engine = create_engine(connection_string, connect_args={'protocol': 'https', 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': False}})

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})
df.to_sql(table, engine, schema=schema, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Big thanks to [@hussein-negm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815367/hussein-negm) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62431369/12394483).